# Mat-DatePicker - [(ngModel)] - not able to show user saved date

Tags: angular, typescript, datepicker, angular-material

Could someone tell how to show user saved date in Mat-Datepicker?

initially  am getting endDate as null from get service (data from nested object, that calling from another component ). when going to edit mode. am selecting value and save it. In console, it prints selected date. but in Network it goes null.

```
this.endDate: string;

<mat-form-field>
<input matInput [value] = "endDate" [matDatepicker]="myDatepicker"  name="endDate" [(ngModel)]="endDate">
<mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="myDatepicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
<mat-datepicker #myDatepicker ></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

in save method:

```
save(){
let obj = {
    endDate = this.endDate; // my ngModel
    }
}
updateChange(d){
this.endDate = d; // i can see the changed value here but not able to save
}
```

actual object for saving data

```
const sample : OriginalModel = { 
demoKey : this.sample['key'].demo, 
demoKey2 : this.sample['key2'].demo2, 
endDate : this.endDate 
}
```

how to get this done to show user saved value in edit mode ?

kindly share solution/ working stackblitz .

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you trying to wrap your object like that?

Comment: well actually is part of object for sample purpose. my object will be like 

`const sample : OriginalModel = {
demoKey : this.sample['key'].demo,
demoKey2 : this.sample['key2'].demo2,
endDate : this.endDate
}`

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you are trying to wrap your date value into `{}` but you can achieve this by using following syntax,

Your component side,

```
sample: any = { demoKey: "", demoKey2: "", demoKey3: "", endDate: new Date }
```

On your html side,

```
<mat-form-field>
<input  matInput placeholder="demoKey1" name='demoKey' [(ngModel)]='sample.demoKey' >
...
</mat-form-field>
```

You don't need to use save function to set two way binding variables, try to console log `obj.endDate` with a function instead and see how magic happens.

[Here is](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zm1bnv) stackblitz example for your case, hope it will help.

[image: Stackblitz view]

Comment: pls check my last comment . thats my actual obj structure for saving data

Comment: can you pls make stackblitz ..  i tried your solution. not working for me

Comment: OK. Give me some time.

Comment: sure.. am also trying. :)

Comment: your stackblitz not loading properly . show blank page

Comment: now i could see that.. let me make use of your solution with my code

Comment: @rcanpahali man I'm comparing your blitz example, even copy/pasting it to my project, and still dates are not updated in the model, what could be wrong here? all other fields updates properly is just a problem with Dates, the only major difference against your blitz is that i'm using the latest angular/angular material versions. Any Clue?